# How to test an async method (not explicitly using fetch) mocking its return value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I want to test Stripe function createToken, and check if it is saved into the state in React but I can not find a way to mock the response.

So far I have tried to mock the function with jest but when I run the test I can see that the function is never called.

Here is my Parent component. On the child component there is a button that activate the function "sendPayment". In the child component I tested if this function was called, so now the idea is to create a wrapper with enzyme and run the function.

```
var stripe = require('stripe-client')(STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);

class StripePayment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      number: '',
      exp_year: '',
      exp_month: '',
      cvc: '',
      error: '',
      token: ''
    };
  }

  handleOnChangeText = (text, cardAttribute) => {
    this.setState({
      [cardAttribute]: text,
    });
  };

  sendPayment = () => {
      //
      stripe.createToken(this.createCard())
      .then(resp => this.setState({token: resp.id}))
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({
          error,
        })
      );
  };

  createCard = () => {
    let informations = {};
    information.card = {};
    Object.keys(this.state)
      .filter(key => !['error','token'].includes(key))
      .forEach(filteredKey => (information.card[filteredKey] = this.state[filteredKey]));
    return informations;
  };

  render() {
    return <StripeForm sendPayment={this.sendPayment} error={this.state.error} />;
  }
}

StripePayment.navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
};
export default StripePayment;
```

The test I wrote so far:

```
  it('should save token to state', async () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<StripePaymentScreen />)
      const instance = wrapper.instance()
      const response = {id: 'token'}
      jest.spyOn(stripe, 'createToken').mockImplementation(() => response);
      await instance.sendPayment();
      expect(stripe.createToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(instance.state.data).toEqual({ token: 'token' });
  });
```

Or alternatively

```
describe('StripePayment', () => {
  let stripe;
  beforeEach(() => {
    stripe = {
      createToken : jest.fn()
    };
  });
  it('should save token to state', async () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<StripePaymentScreen />)
      const instance = wrapper.instance()
      const response = {id: 'token'}
      jest.spyOn(stripe, 'createToken').mockImplementation(() => response);
      stripe.createToken.mockResolvedValue(response);
      await instance.sendPayment();
      expect(stripe.createToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(instance.state.data).toEqual({ token: 'token' });
  });
});
```

Comment: I was supposed to write instance.state.token, but it is not changing